# I cannot see intellisense for firebase-fucntions or any other built-in function in VS Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My problem is exactly as in title. When I write anything, VS Code suggests nothing but things that I've already written.

[image]

It suggested `firebase`. Because above I wrote `const functions = require('firebase-functions');` It recognizes `firebase` from there.

[image]

Whenever I type something that I've not wrote before, it fails to suggest. Also even if I have all required `node_modules`, I cannot see source code from `index.js`.

I don't know if it helps but here is how my project looks like:

[image]

---

**Edit:** I switch IDE from VS Code to Webstrom. Now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install firebase & firebase tools globally  as follow :

   npm i -g firebase firebase-tools

2.go to the project directory and also save it to the project dependencies :

```
npm i firebase firebase-tools --save
```

3. install VS extension : ***npm intellisense***

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It works partially. Now it shows syntax error. But still doesn't   show intellisense.

Comment: Still, it doesn't show source code and give any intellisence. And also gives an error on `const functions = require('firebase-functions');` and says that `Extra semicolon. (semi)standard(semi)`